# taskqueue and non-idempotent tasks

Tags: python, google-app-engine, task-queue, idempotent

I'm working on a voting app, where the user can upload a list of email addresses for all of the voters.  After doing some error checking, I create a `Voter` entity for each voter.  Since there can be a large number of voters, I create the `Voter` entities in a taskqueue to avoid the 30 second limit and the task looks like this:

```
    put_list = []
    for email, id in itertools.izip(voter_emails, uuids):
        put_list.append(Voter(election = election,
                              email = email,
                              uuid = id))
    election.txt_voters = ""
    put_list.append(election)
    db.put(put_list)
```

This task, however, isn't idempotent.  Is there a way to make this task idempotent?  Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a key_name rather than a uuid property to prevent creating duplicate voter entities.

Comment: I like this idea, but I'm concerned with the number of datastore calls.  In the above code there is just one put.  To use named keys, I think I'd have to call get_or_insert for a each voter (a very large number) plus the one put.  Is it possible to do bulk operations with named keys?

Comment: you should be able to use `put()` even with a key_name, and and the new instance will replace all of the properties on the old.  It's not clear what you need the uuid's for at all.  I would probably do this something like `Voter(parent=election, key_name=email)`

Comment: @TokenMacGuy, using email as the key name is a good idea.  I need the UUID to prevent voter fraud (UUID is sent to voter's email).  I think I don't want the Voter to be in the same entity group as the Election but I'm going to ask another question about that.

Comment: @TokenMacGuy, actually I can't use the email as the key name since it isn't guaranteed to be unique (the same email could be used in two different elections).  I guess I could prepend some kind of unique ID for the election.